# Unity c# bypass listener effects are not working on IOS devices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to play mp3 in Unity App. While development bypass listener effects are working perfectly in Unity Simulator but on real iOS devices bypass listener effects is not showing up.

Is this something issue in creating build or Please suggest!

What is the best way to run mp3 in Unity C#?

Answer (score 0):

I never build in iOS device, but checking the bypass listener effects should disabling any listener effects...
i suggest a way to run mp3 in Unity3D is by defining AudioSource inside gameObject then use GetComponent for the AudioSource, add a script to Play() those mp3...
or give a check on Play on Awake

Comment: Thanks, Jojaned, It is perfectly working on all android devices, Unity simulator except real iOS device (Which is actual issue). FYI, I have a headphone with lights which flash out when I enable bypass listener effects while listening to music.

Comment: Yeah, those happened to me too when i forgot to increase my volume bar, yet i confused why i can't hear any sfx